# Exchange Account recieves emails internally but not externally

Tags: exchange-2003

I created an new exchange account, if we send  emails to this address from inside the domain it works just fine, they are delivered with no problem.

if you send him an email from any address outside the domain it is returned to the user saying the delivery failed.

What Can I check in exchange to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

This is all hotmail tells me when it returns it:

> This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.
>   Delivery to the following recipients failed.

Here is what gmail returned:

> Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 553 553 mailbox.... is restricted (Mode: normal) (state 14).

Comment: What's the NDR message?

Comment: I updated my question with the messages from hotmail and gmail

Comment: Are there any delivery restrictions in place for the user? Go to ADUC -> <The User> -> Exchange General Tab -> Delivery Restrictions button -> *Messages from everyone* should be checked and *From authenticated users* should be unchecked.

Comment: I double checked there are no delivery restrictions, they only one that is checked is "from everyone"

Comment: Anything weird on your SMTP connector this user is going through? Do you use any third party services such as MessageLabs which filter mail for you?

Comment: Has the user logged into the mailbox? Do you use any type of filter or service, such as Postini? If so, is the user configured/enabled with the filter or service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of things. Starting with the basics or ports and DNS? Is the exchange server publicly aval? MX records setup for the domain and pointed to your exchange server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. to answer your questions...yes.Everyother account(over 100) work just fine. it is just this new one, which was created last week, though not used until today.

Comment: are the other accounts that are working using the same domain name?

Comment: yes they are in the same domain.

Comment: perhaps delete and recreate the account?

Comment: I found the issue was with the MX not the exchange server. We solved it thank you!